# How to label individual points with vectors in R

Tags: r, vector, label, scatter-plot

I'm pretty new to coding and R in general. I'm trying to figure out how to create plots both as individual points as well as vectors. I should be getting the same result for both options, but I can't seem to figure out how to correlate the labels for the points when using vectors.

[Here's the table I was given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E83j9.png)

Here's my code for the individual plotting and the [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ8sN.png)

```
plot(
        x = NULL,
        xlim = c(0, 8),
        ylim = c(0, 10),
        main = "Problem 3a- Individual Points Fuction",
        xlab = "x",
        ylab = "y",
        las = 1
    )

text( 0.6, 7.5, "A" )
points( 1, 7, pch = 19, cex = 3, col = "navy" )

text( 3.4, 2.5, "B" )
points( 4, 3, pch = 15, cex = 6, col = "blueviolet" )

text( 5.6, 4.0, "C" )
points( 6, 5, pch = 17, cex = 4, col = "firebrick2" )

text( 1.6, 1.5, "D" )
points( 2, 2, pch = 18, cex = 5, col = "cyan3" )

text( 6.8, 3.5, "E" )
points( 7, 4, pch = 16, cex = 2, col = "seagreen3" )
```

Here's my code for the vector method, with the [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIWBv.png):

```
plot(
        x = NULL,
        xlim = c(0, 8),
        ylim = c(0, 10),
        main = "Problem 3b- Vector Points Fuction",
        xlab = "x",
        ylab = "y",
        las = 1
    )

points(

x = c(1, 4, 6, 2, 7),

y = c(7, 3, 5, 2, 4),

pch = c(19, 15, 17, 18, 16),

cex = c(3, 6, 4, 5, 2),

col = c("navy", "blueviolet", "firebrick2", "cyan3", "seagreen3"),

)
```

I can't seem to figure out how to label the points on the vector, and have it labeled at certain coordinates. I've tried just putting Text = ("A", "B", etc) as well as trying to make that a vector too (text = c("A",etc), but I keep getting errors. Any advice and resources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `text` function as shown below. I added the `xDisp` variable to easily setup the labels position (if needed you can add a `yDisp` variable as well for vertical position).

```
xDisp = -0.5

  plot(
    x = NULL,
    xlim = c(0, 8),
    ylim = c(0, 10),
    main = "Problem 3b- Vector Points Fuction",
    xlab = "x",
    ylab = "y",
    las = 1
  )

  points(

    x = c(1, 4, 6, 2, 7),

    y = c(7, 3, 5, 2, 4),

    pch = c(19, 15, 17, 18, 16),

    cex = c(3, 6, 4, 5, 2),

    col = c("navy", "blueviolet", "firebrick2", "cyan3", "seagreen3")

  )

  text(

    x = c(1+xDisp, 4+xDisp, 6+xDisp, 2+xDisp, 7+xDisp), y = c(7, 3, 5, 2, 4), labels = c("A","B","C","D","E")

  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! That makes a lot more sense and is easier to read too!